# TSQL Query From SQL Server 2012 Database, two different tables, One Parent, One Child

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have two tables, `TableA` and `TableB`.  `TableB` has a `FK` to `TableA`.  This is a SQL Server 2012 database, with primary keys on both tables called `Id.`  No other indexes exists yet.

The first table as `TableA` holds who has access to a folder with the following columns:

- `Id` (RowId, Primary Key)
- `Path` (full path of folder / directory, nvarchar(255))
- `GroupName` (Active Directory Group, nvarchar(255))
- `Guid` (Guid of Group, nvarchar(128))

The second table as `TableB` holds permissions to that folder or directory:

- `Id` (RowId, Primary Key)
- `TableARowId` (FK, RowId from TableA)
- `Permission` (nvarchar(128), 12 different possible values)

What I've been asked to do is to query `Path`, `GroupName`, `Guid`, and `Permissions` for all the folders.  No big deal.

The problem is if the groups and permissions from a particular folder in the path (example: `\\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\`) is the same all the way down to its lowest level (`\\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\`....`\Folder[N]`), they only want to see up to the first folder that has the same Groups and Permissions.

So, if `FolderB` has different Groups and Permissions than `FolderA` then all the needed fields will be in the dataset for that path.  If `FolderC` has different  groups and permissions than `FolderB`, then all needed fields will be in the dataset for that path.

But If `FolderC` has the same number of Groups and Permissions all the way down to `FolderW`, then the last folder in the dataset for that path will be `FolderC`.  That is the part that I can't figure out.

I guessed the answer should include a recursive CTE with the anchor being the root directory.  But I thought the recursion should compare the last folder's groups and permissions to the previous record, and if it is different, add it to the dataset, otherwise, skip it.

But there is something I couldn't get past while trying to answer my first question.  How do you code for scenario of FolderA - FolderC being different, then FolderC to FolderP being the same, then, FolderP to FolderZ are different?  In this case, I still want so show all folders up to FolderP.  This is the part that hurts my head.

The code I wrote didn't get me very far.  I wrote:

```
        (SELECT 
           [Path]
          ,[GroupName]
          ,[Guid]
          ,PermissionAsOneRow
      FROM [TableA] TA INNER JOIN 
            (  SELECT [TableARowId], PermissionAsOneRow FROM (
            SELECT  [Id], TBL1.[TableARowId], 
                 ( SELECT [Permission] + ', '
                  FROM [TableB] TBL2
                  WHERE TBL2.[TableARowId] = TBL1.[TableARowId]
                    FOR XML PATH('')) AS PermissionAsOneRow
                FROM [TableB] TBL1
                GROUP BY  [Id], TBL1.[TableARowId]) AS MYDATA
        GROUP BY [TableARowId], PermissionAsOneRow) AS MD ON TA.Id = MD.[TableARowId])
```

This gives me data that looks like this:

```
      Id          Path                                   GroupName           Guid                          Permission
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           \\FolderA\FolderB\                           SomeGroupNameA     [RandomGuidValueHereA]         PermissionA,PermissionB,PermissionC,PermissionD
2           \\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\                   SomeGroupNameB     [RandomGuidValueHereB]         PermissionA,PermissionB,PermissionC,PermissionD
3           \\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\...Folder[N]       SomeGroupNameC     [RandomGuidValueHereC]         PermissionA,PermissionB,PermissionC
```

I organized the data this way because I thought it would be easy to compare row after row on the permissions field as I discussed above, using the Recursive CTE.  But the honestly, I didn't know how to do the next step and started to think it wouldn't work.

Any and all help is appreciated.

For those that can answer, please explain so I can learn from it.

See below for example of data, please excuse my formatting

Example of data in TableA

```
Id          Path                                         GroupName        Guid 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           \\FolderA\FolderB\                           SomeGroupNameA     [RandomGuidValueHereA]
2           \\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\                   SomeGroupNameB     [RandomGuidValueHereB]
3           \\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\...Folder[N]       SomeGroupNameC     [RandomGuidValueHereC]
4           \\FolderAA\FolderBB\FolderCC\                SomeGroupNameD     [RandomGuidValueHereD]
5           \\FolderAA\FolderBB\FolderCC\...Folder[N]    SomeGroupNameE     [RandomGuidValueHereE]
```

Example of Data in TableB

```
Id         TableARowId    Permission
--------------------------
1               1         PermissionA
2               1         PermissionB
3               1         PermissionC
4               1         PermissionD
5               2         PermissionA
6               2         PermissionB
7               2         PermissionC
```

Comment: You may want to format your sample data using `{ }` code blocks and present them differently (like databases do). Also, consider adding your approach - query which you have tried.

Comment: I updated the sample data @ConsiderMe, Thanks.

Comment: You should really show the sample data formatted as **tables** - much easier to read and understand !

Comment: Dude, "pivot" your text. Don't start a paragraph for each new row - draw a table (isn't it obvious when you are talking about a table) with rows and cols. And the best one is to give a ready to execute code that will create a sample table with those rows. And provide a result you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for formatting @marc_s

Comment: I'm still not seeing a complete set of input and desired output, just some unrelated sample rows. Perhaps if `TableA` _had_ an `Id` column and the expected output was included that provides samples of the various cases to be handled we could be of more help. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @HABO, both tables have id columns, if you look towards the top of the page, there is a description of each table. In that description, the first field of each table are Id columns as the primary key that is auto generated.  In TableB, there is a FK to tableA as `TableARowId`.  I'll make it clearer so you and others understand.

Comment: *my employer screens for code* isn't our problem. You can provide sample data without posting code, and sample results, without an issue. I'm quite certain you can also figure out a way to post what you've attempted so far that isn't working for you. We're not a code writing service; we expect you to have made an effort to solve the problem yourself before posting here, and to include that effort in your post. Your employer apparently has no difficulties with your posting tables and volumes of text here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little perplexed by what you want, but there may be something of use in this:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Folders as Table ( FolderId Int Identity, Folder VarChar(16) );
insert into @Folders ( Folder ) values
  ( '\\A0\' ), ( '\\A0\A1\' ), ( '\\A0\A1\A2\' ), ( '\\A0\A1\A2\A3\' ),
  ( '\\B0\' ), ( '\\B0\B1\' ), ( '\\B0\B1\B2\' ), ( '\\B0\B1\B2\B3\' ),
  ( '\\C0\' ), ( '\\C0\C1\' ), ( '\\C0\C1\C2\' ), ( '\\C0\C1\C2\C3\' ),
  ( '\\D0\' ), ( '\\D0\D1\' ), ( '\\D0\D1\D2\' ), ( '\\D0\D1\D2\D3\' );

declare @Permissions as Table ( PermissionId Int Identity, Permission VarChar(32) );
insert into @Permissions ( Permission ) values
  ( 'Create' ), ( 'Delete' ), ( 'Read' ), ( 'Write' ), ( 'Corrupt' );

select * from @Folders;
select * from @Permissions;

-- It is assumed that all root folders have permissions explicitly specified.
declare @FolderPermissions as Table ( FolderId Int, PermissionId Int );
insert into @FolderPermissions ( FolderId, PermissionId ) values
  ( 1, 3 ), ( 1, 4 ),
  ( 3, 3 ), ( 3, 4 ),
  ( 5, 3 ), ( 5, 4 ),
  ( 6, 3 ), ( 6, 4 ), ( 6, 1 ), ( 6, 2 ),
  ( 9, 3 ), ( 9, 4 ), ( 9, 1 ), ( 9, 2 ),
  ( 11, 3 ), ( 11, 4 ),
  ( 13, 1 ), ( 13, 2 ),
  ( 14, 3 ), ( 14, 4 ),
  ( 16, 5 );

-- Dump the sample data.
select Folder,
  Stuff( ( select ',' + Permission from @Permissions as P inner join @FolderPermissions as FP on FP.PermissionId = P.PermissionId where FP.FolderId = F.FolderId order by P.PermissionId asc for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'VarChar(max)' ), 1, 1, '' ) as Permissions
  from @Folders as F
  order by Folder;

-- Generate a folder tree with inherited permissions.
with FoldersWithDepths as (
  -- Depth   is zero for root folders, 1 for children of roots, ... .
  select FolderId, Folder, Len( Folder ) - Len( Replace( Folder, '\', '' ) ) - 3 as Depth,
    Stuff( ( select ',' + Permission from @Permissions as P inner join @FolderPermissions as FP on FP.PermissionId = P.PermissionId where FP.FolderId = F.FolderId order by P.PermissionId asc for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'VarChar(max)' ), 1, 1, '' ) as Permissions
    from @Folders as F ),
  FolderTree as (
    -- Start with root folders.
    select FolderId, Folder, Depth, Permissions, Cast( 1 as Bit ) as PermissionsChanged, Cast( NULL as Int ) as ParentFolderId
      from FoldersWithDepths
      where Depth = 0
    union all
    -- Add children on the way down while inheriting permissions from their parents if no permissions are explicitly specified.
    select Child.FolderId, Child.Folder, Child.Depth, Coalesce( Child.Permissions, Parent.Permissions ),
      Cast( case when Coalesce( Child.Permissions, Parent.Permissions ) = Parent.Permissions then 0 else 1 end as Bit ), Parent.FolderId
      from FolderTree as Parent inner join
        FoldersWithDepths as Child on Child.Depth = Parent.Depth + 1 and Child.Folder like Parent.Folder + '_%\' )
  select FolderId, Depth, ParentFolderId, Replicate( ' ', Depth * 2 ) + Folder as Folder,
    PermissionsChanged, Permissions
    from FolderTree
--    where PermissionsChanged = 1 -- Controls whether all folders are shown or only those which have permissions not matching their parents'.
    order by FolderTree.Folder;
```

Debugging/comprehension aid: You can change the final `select` to `select * from FoldersWithDepths` to see the intermediate results.

Comment: Wow. Thank You @HABO, I've been looking at the code for the last 10mins digesting it.  I'm surprised one CTE can get this off.  Can't wait to get a chance to run it.  I greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @JasonR. Was that _the answer_?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out this way.  This was a table populated by a SSIS job from a C# script.  There was already a script that inserted all differences to a table, which is the source table for this question.  I wrote a second script that populated a second table with the results I was looking for.  As I enumerated through the folders, If there was a difference from the one folder to it's sub-folder, I inserted everything I wanted to know.  If there wasn't, I skipped the insert until there was.  That got me what I was looking for.  I'd still like to try and figure it out in the future though.

Comment: thanks for your help though.  I played with your code for a while until I wrote the script.  I don't think it was far off.  This reminded me I had it and I will play with it again soon just for my own knowledge.